# How can multiple values be replaced with other values in a large dataset?

Tags: r, variables, replace, numeric, recode

In R, I have variables with over 40.000 observations in a large dataset and I would like to replace certain numeric values with other numeric values. Let's say, the variable `VX` is coded from `0 to 10` and I would like to recode this variable from `1 to 11`. This variable belongs to the dataset `df`. I would welcome your responses!

Comment: do you just mean`df$VX <- df$VX+1` ... ??

Comment: I mean, the variable VX takes values from 0 to 10. I would like to have the same variable, but this variable takes values from 1 to 11.

Comment: So that 0 is 1 , 1 is 2, 3 is 4....

Comment: ...or `df$VX <- df$VX + 1`, for those who prefer the `<-` form of the [assignment operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html)?

Comment: I get the error message: Error in newdata$trstep1 + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: I have already omitted the missing values

Comment: @User1811 so it sounds like your variable isn't numeric after all... what is `class(newdata$trstep1)`? Once we know that, we can convert it to numeric, and then adding 1 to it will work.

Comment: It is a "character"

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, one can use the assignment operator to modify the value of an existing column in a data frame, or vector. The following code creates a data frame with a single column, `VX` that ranges from 0 - 10. We then use the assignment operator to recode it to the range of 1 - 11.

```
df <- data.frame(VX = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))    
df$VX <- df$VX + 1
# print the resulting data frame    
df
```

...and the output:

```
> df
   VX
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
11 11
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!